# d3.hexbin plugin - dynamically define colour domain to suit data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am developing a Hexagonal Binning page using the d3.hexbin plugin (http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4248145).

I have managed to dynamically define the domain of the axes using the minimum and maximum values from my data.

I would however like to dynamically generate the bin color domain based on the points variable.

The example bins are coloured according to the following code:

```
var color = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, 20])
    .range(["white", "steelblue"])
    .interpolate(d3.interpolateLab);
```

The color range is mapped to values ranging between 0 and 20. For large data sets, there are often hexagon bins with more than 20 points and the chart is 'saturated’.

Can the color domain values [0,20] be dynamically generated based on the data? Is it possible to obtain the max and minimum number of points allocated to the bins from the hexbin object somehow?

Appreciate your help as I’m not too hot on JavaScript.

Comment: can you not create a function that returns maximum values from you data then use those variables in your domain ?

Comment: There exists a function in d3 for this - d3.extent - which returns the lowest and highest value for a column. I require to know the maximum number of data elements which fall within the bins (calculated within the hexbin.js object). This number is d.length for each bin, but I don't know how to access the maximum and minimum d.length for all the hexbin bins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd try the approach used in this hexbin example: http://projects.delimited.io/experiments/hexbins/starbucks.html

That is to define the domain as a function of the mean & standard deviation of bin size. Translating that back to the original Mike Bostock example:

1. Create an array of all the bin sizes:

   ```
   var bins = hexbin(points);
   var counts = [];
   bins.map(function (elem) {
       counts.push(elem.length)
   });
   ```
2. Set the color domain based on the `counts` array:

   ```
   color.domain([0, (ss.mean(counts) + (ss.standard_deviation(counts) * 3))]);
   ```

In this example, ss is the [simple_statistics.js library](http://www.macwright.org/simple-statistics/docs/simple_statistics.html), but you could just as easily roll your own or just set the domain maximum to be the highest value in `counts` like this:

```
color.domain([0, d3.max(counts)]);
```

Here's a working fiddle with the color domain calculated dynamically: http://jsfiddle.net/henbox/3jecfdfu/2/